# Force Http status when requesting a particolar html page in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

there is a way in Angular to force an http status code after requesting a particolar html page?

I want to force a 404 status when requesting a page with an particolar url for example: https://www.example.com/path/path?query=3.com

Comment: You wan't to Intercept the answer and override the status ? Or you wan't to intercept the request and create a fake response with a 404 status ?

Comment: I want to intercept the answer and override the status...so you suggest to user the interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can retrieve the requested url int the response in an [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) interceptor.

Try this:

```
myModule.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.url === "http://test.com")
               response.status = 404;
            return response;
        }
    };
});


myModule.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
});
```